# Opensocial: error "path" is undefined. In gadgets.js file

Tags: javascript, opensocial

I'm creating a gadgets in OSDE. And in all gadgets I have JS error in gadgets.js file that "C is undefined. Can't get "path" property." Also I have second error that gadgets.log.LogAtLevel is not a function.

Could you please help? Because it's opensocial files and I can't change it.